# count words within a span tag

Tags: php, html, tags

I need to count the number of words within the span tag...The text is usually similar to

```
This<span class="highlight_word"> function is useful to highlight words from a simple non-html </span>text.The<span class="highlight_word"><span class="highlight_word"><span class="highlight_word"> regular expression, as a pattern, can match all kinds of text strings helping your application </span></span>validate, compare, compute, decide etc\. </span>With<span class="highlight_word"><span class="highlight_word"><span class="highlight_word"> the temperature up on keywords and searches, many sites have opted </span></span>for highlighting the keywords from their searches\. This can be useful for quickly finding relavant words withing large pages of text\. </span>
```

Can anyone guide me as how to count the number of words within the span tags.

Thanks

Comment: How do you want the count returned? A single count (i.e. xyz words are between span tags total), a count per set of span tags? How do you want nested tags handled? `<span>words <span>more words</span> more</span>` What do you expect for this example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On server side, the following counts the words in the span tags in one counter, but you can do this separately for all span elements.

```
$text = 'This<span class="highlight_word"> function is useful to highlight words from a simple non-html </span>text.The<span class="highlight_word"><span class="highlight_word"><span class="highlight_word"> regular expression, as a pattern, can match all kinds of text strings helping your application </span></span>validate, compare, compute, decide etc\. </span>With<span class="highlight_word"><span class="highlight_word"><span class="highlight_word"> the temperature up on keywords and searches, many sites have opted </span></span>for highlighting the keywords from their searches\. This can be useful for quickly finding relavant words withing large pages of text\. </span>';
$words = 0;
preg_match_all("'span[^>]*[>]([^<]+?)[<]/span'is",$text,$matches);
foreach ($matches[1] as $v)
{
    $words += count(explode(" ",trim($v)));
}
```

**UPDATE:** i corrcted the regexp a bit

Answer (score 0):

can be done using following two functions

```
function getTextBetweenTags($string, $tagname)
 {
    $pattern = "/<$tagname>(.*?)<\/$tagname>/";
    preg_match($pattern, $string, $matches);
    return $matches[1];
 }


function count_words($str) 
 {
 $no = count(explode(" ",$str));
 return $no;
 }
```

Comment: What about the built in function `str_word_count()` for counting words instead of your custom one?